# Is a Join equivalent to a query with a subquery for a column?

Tags: sql

Sorry for the newbie sql questions but isn't this the same thing:

```
select a.productid, sum(b.qty)
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on b.productid = a.productid
group by a.productid
;

select a.productid
,(select sum(b.qty) from table2 b where b.productid = a.productid)
from table1 a
group by a.productid
;
```

Why would anyone ever use a query like above in the select, is this some old school thing to forget about using or should I still consider using it for some possible future problems?

Comment: May I suggest another title for your question please? Something like "Is a Join equivalent to a query with a subquery for a column ?" for example

Comment: yes makes sense, is it possible for me to change title now after posting?

Comment: You probably cannot edit (not sure though) because you are new. With enough reputation/points you will be able to. I will do that. I understand that you are ok with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not in fact the same thing.  There are multiple differences, but the most obvious is that the `join` will filter out any unmatching rows.  The correlated subquery will return all rows in the first table.

There are other differences as well.  The `sum()`s will not be the same if there are duplicate `productid`s in the first table.  The execution plans are going to be different (because the result sets are different).  Under some circumstances, the correlated subquery will be faster.

More generally, there are situations where the correlated subquery is the simplest way to express logic.  And, as mentioned above, it can also produce the fastest execution plan under some circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

First query:

```
select a.productid, sum(b.qty)
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on b.productid = a.productid
group by a.productid
```

It won't return row if there is no corresponding value in table2.

Second query is like `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select a.productid
,(select sum(b.qty) from table2 b where b.productid = a.productid)
from table1 a
group by a.productid
<=>
select a.productid, sum(b.qty)
from table1 a
left join table2 b on b.productid = a.productid
group by a.productid
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep performance in mind... inner join is much faster than subselect. A subselect loops through all matching results, so complexity is N x M... causing poor performance. Joins have a better performance in most cases.

See https://www.essentialsql.com/subquery-versus-inner-join/

Comment: This is simply a false statement.  Sometimes correlated subqueries are faster than joins.

Comment: @Gordon, I agree with you that subqueries could be faster (e.g. when DB optimizer can improve the execution plan). This is why I wrote _in most cases_. If you feel my answer is incorect in general, please provide any evidence.

Comment: . . . "inner join is much faster than subselect."  False.